# is unity available for PCs running old unsupported versions such as v9.10

Tags: unity

My Clients keep asking me to use unity in their OLD version"ubuntu" PCs
so is it available in old version also?

if yes, how? if no, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity is open-source, i.e. it can be used on debian or Arch. It just takes effort and a lot of time (which nobody has done yet).

From what I know, unity was too much work to be backported to 10.10 let alone 9.10.

So, in short, your answer would be no!